# Prove $\frac{(n/2)!(n/2)!}{\left(\frac{n+i}2\right)!\left(\frac{n-i}2\right)!}=\prod_{j=1}^{i/2}\frac{\frac n2+1-j}{\frac n2+j}$

Tags: factorial, products

I have a textbook (*Asymptopia* by Joel Spencer, [p.66](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8FyH.png)) that states that

$$\frac{(n/2)!(n/2)!}{\left(\frac{n+i}2\right)!\left(\frac{n-i}2\right)!} =\prod_{j=1}^{i/2}\frac{\frac n2+1-j}{\frac n2+j}.$$

The equivalence between the LHS and $\left(\prod_{j=1}^{n/2}j^2\right)\left(\prod_{j=1}^{(n+i)/2}j^{-1}\right)\left(\prod_{j=1}^{(n-i)/2}j^{-1}\right)$ I understand, it results from the product notation form of the factorial and some simple algebraic manipulation. However, for the life of me, I don't see how you can then manipulate it to get the form of the RHS. I've numerically tested it out with different values, so I believe that it is true. For example, if $n=20$ and $i=2$, all terms equal $10/11$. Could someone help explain how one arrives at the RHS expression?

Edit:  I believe that the book implies that, due to the use of $n$ even, or the floor of $n/2$, $i$ should be even.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes you are correct about the $\frac{k}/{2}$s. And I think your choice of title is very appropriate, thank you.

Comment: There seems to be a problem if both $n$ and $i$ are odd, like for instance $n=5,i=3$.

Comment: @AnneBauval huh you're right. I believe that the book implies that, due to the use of $n$ even, or the floor of $n/2$, that $i$ should be even. Here's the page that its from for context: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LZaf_k9BhSom1Hh3aTz1My9Vz_F0zSLm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for these new informations! I took the liberty to update your post, to make it more consistent with your source, and include your comment.

Comment: https://xyproblem.info The "second term" in your post was from you, not from your textbook as you said, and was misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $n$ and $i$ are even. Then,

$$\frac{(n/2)!(n/2)!}{\left(\frac{n+i}2\right)!\left(\frac{n-i}2\right)!}=\frac AB$$
where
$$A=\frac{(n/2)!}{\left(\frac{n-i}2\right)!}=\prod_{k=\frac{n-i}2+1}^{n/2}k=\prod_{j=1}^{i/2}\left(\frac n2+1-j\right)$$
and
$$B=\frac{\left(\frac{n+i}2\right)!}{(n/2)!}=\prod_{k=\frac n2+1}^{(n+i)/2}k=\prod_{j=1}^{i/2}\left(\frac n2+j\right).$$

Comment: Thank you! That split of the terms into those fractional terms is very clever! I had gotten myself stuck on trying to manipulate just the top or the bottom as they were into the right forms, which I see now is not the correct approach.